# Update intermediary npm dependencies with package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package-lock.json, npm-update

What is the proper way to update an intermediary dependency with npm in the presence of the [package-lock.json file](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json)?

For example:

```
$ npm outdated --depth=1 eslint
Package  Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
eslint     4.9.0  4.10.0  4.10.0  MyApplication1 > grunt-eslint
```

The package-lock.json is doing its job by keeping eslint (an intermediary dependency, in this case for grunt-eslint) at 4.9.0. How do I update to eslint@4.10?

I have tried the following commands but npm doesn't do anything:

```
npm update grunt-eslint --dev --depth 1
npm update eslint --dev
```

It works if I add eslint as a top-level dependency but I don't think that is the correct way to do this.

Comment: What about `npm install --save-dev eslint`?  Instead of `update`?

Comment: @zero298 That works but it would cause the dependency to be saved as a top-level dependency and also it isn't feasible to do this for intermediary dependencies at varying depth

Comment: Did you try `npm install eslint@4.10.0 --dev --depth 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clearly a hacky workaround but it serves the purpose:

```
npm install eslint --save-dev && npm uninstall eslint --save-dev
```

I'll be happy to accept another answer if there is a better method of doing this.